# create zip files with arabic characters

Tags: java, file, encoding, zip, apache-poi

i have the following situation 
i have to modify an existing files and return a zip containing this modified files , i'm in web application  context 
what i done up to now is :

```
///////////////// modifying the existing file with poi librairy 
    FileInputStream inpoi = new   FileInputStream("file_path");
                POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(inpoi);
                HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
                Range r = doc.getRange();
                r.replaceText("<nomPrenom>","test"); 
               byte[] b =   doc.getDataStream();

//////////////////////// create the zip file and copy the modified files into it 
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("my.zip"));
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file"));
for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                out.write(b[j]);
              }
```

the created zipped file can't be read correctly with word given that the original file is wrotten in arabic

i tried to this :

```
 try {
                 FileInputStream inpoi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\blame.doc");
                    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(inpoi);
                    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
                    Range r = doc.getRange();
                    r.replaceText("<nomPrenom>","test"); 
                  byte[] stream=   doc.getDataStream();
                  String encoding = "utf-16";
                  ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("yyy.zip"));
                   ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file.doc");
                   OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out,"utf-8");
                    out.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    for (int j = 0; j < stream.length; j++) {
                        writer.write(stream[j]);  
                  }
                  writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
```

it doesn't work

Comment: Have a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260325/why-is-java-bufferedreader-not-reading-arabic-and-chinese-characters-correctly

Comment: i don't think it's matter of encoding because i tried with french files , i think it's problem of reading stream properly

Answer (score 2):

There was an old bug in java zip implementation. It should be fixed in v7. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4244499

Comment: btw what build number has your java?

Comment: what do you mean by build number ?

Comment: If I run 'java -version' I got something like that ' ... Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)'. IMO b147 is the build. The bug database tells since b57 it should be fixed. So it should work on my machine. I will test it next days.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use apache commons-io FileUtils offer alot of handy methods for Java File operation - reading and writing files etc...

The read and write Methods also have an encoding parameters.

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

ZipFile allows you to set the proper encoding.

ZipFile(String name, String encoding)
Opens the given file for reading, assuming the specified encoding for file names, scanning unicode extra fields.

Comment: i don't think it's matter of encoding because i tried with french files , i think it's problem of reading stream properly