# Arabic Files Names corrupted when using ZipOutputStream and ZipEntry

Tags: java, arabic

When I using **ZipOutputStream** and **ZipEntry** to compress some files into one zip file, I found the Arabic Files Names were corrupted when I decompress the zip file, although the English files names are correct .

e.g. `╪┤╪▒┘â╪⌐ ╪º┘å╪╕┘à╪⌐ ╪º┘ä╪º╪¬╪╡╪º┘ä╪º╪¬ ┘ê╪º┘ä╪¡┘ä┘ê┘ä ╪º┘ä╪ú┘à┘å┘è╪⌐ ╪º┘ä┘à╪¡╪»┘ê╪»╪⌐`

### Instead of: `بيان المشاريع السابقة`

Java Version : 1.6

## My code (Start point convertToZip) :

```
public void convertToZip(OAApplicationModule oaapplicationmodule,Number AuctionHeaderID)
  {
        OADBTransaction oadbtransaction = oaapplicationmodule.getOADBTransaction();
        OracleResultSet rsZippedEmptyBlob= PrepareNewZipProcess ( oadbtransaction , AuctionHeaderID) ;

        try
        {
            if ( !rsZippedEmptyBlob.next() )
            {
                return ;
            }
            OracleResultSet rLoopSourceBlob =  (OracleResultSet)GetBlobResultSetFromRFX ( oadbtransaction , AuctionHeaderID ) ;
            BLOB zippedEmptyBlob = rsZippedEmptyBlob.getBLOB(1);
            ZipOutputStream zosFinal = new ZipOutputStream ( zippedEmptyBlob.getBinaryOutputStream()); 
            zosFinal.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED); 
            byte[] bytesArrayFromSourceBlob = new byte[1024]; 
            while(rLoopSourceBlob.next())
            {
                BLOB sourceBlobFile = rLoopSourceBlob.getBLOB(1);     
                ZipEntry zippedSingleFileName = new ZipEntry( rLoopSourceBlob.getString(2)  ) ;
                zosFinal.putNextEntry(zippedSingleFileName);
                int lengthRead ;
                InputStream DocumentStream = sourceBlobFile.getBinaryStream();

                while((lengthRead=DocumentStream.read(bytesArrayFromSourceBlob))>=0) //>0
                    {       
                        zosFinal.write(bytesArrayFromSourceBlob,0,lengthRead);
                    }
                sourceBlobFile.getBinaryStream().close();
                zosFinal.closeEntry();
            }
            zosFinal.close();
            oadbtransaction.commit();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            throw OAException.wrapperException(ex);
        }

  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the code you use. Please also provide the names of some sample files.

Comment: What's the Java version you're using?

Comment: I added my code and the java version is 1.6

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598424/create-zip-files-with-arabic-characters

Comment: are you mean the prblem in java version .

Comment: my case for BLOB not for files

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4244499) in JDK6. The [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106367/add-non-ascii-file-names-to-zip-in-java) is produced on any non-ascii file name. To solve this issue you can try either:

1. using JDK7 (b57) or higher
2. or using a different zip library such as [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveOutputStream.html#setEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I need example for using ZipArchiveOutputStream

Comment: No, this will be outside of the scope of your question.